# Calculating distance between two coordinates given that I have drawn my own route

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have seen people asking questions about calculating distance between two geo points and that distance would be the direct line between two points while taking into consideration earth's radius and using the formulas that people have suggested.

In my case I have drawn a bus route on Google map (I am using iOS and kml file that contains the coordinates) and I want to calculate the distance between two bus stops on that route and I want to use the route coordinates that I have described my self. My bus routes are closed loop and there are no shortcuts or multiple ways to get to a point.

Any suggestions how to do that?

thank you,

Comment: Can't you sum the distances between each pair of coordinates in the route?

Comment: I have been thinking about doing it that way but just wanted to know if any one else has tackled this issue in a slick way. thanks